# What's short Command for making comment and Uncomment the Code?

Tags: iphone

Short Command for making comment and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-slash. Simple.

Answer (score 2):

command + /

use these commands for comment and uncomment by selecting code.

Comment: select code which is commented and use the same command but selection of code starts from the point of //(this) and carry on upto selection of the commented code.this works(then accept the ans.)

Comment: @Raman rana if you ones accept this one then why you change the answer.